# How can I find out the current TS segment during a HLS(m3u8) playback in iOS?

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming, m3u8

An HLS (m3u8) file references mpeg-ts files. During its playback in iOS' AVPlayer, how can i determine the currently playing mpeg-ts URI?

Comment: Could you provide a url for your m3u8 file?

Comment: My question is for any generic m3u8 file, you can get an example on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2288/_index.html

Answer (score 3):

If your looking for a reference to the URI of the currently downloading TS, it's not available.  You can get the URI of the stream for the current bit-rate by looking at the current `AVPlayerItem`'s  `-accessLog`.

E.g.:
`[[[player currentItem] accessLog] events]`

It's an `NSArray` of `AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent`'s.

But it's not going to give you the URI of the TS per se.  You may just have to calculate the current TS by where the playhead is currently at in relation to the duration as well as the segment size.

Comment: This will not work in case of adaptive streaming in where you might have different m3u8's for different renditions of the same video.

Comment: I don't think you can calculate the current TS this way because there is no way to get the initial offset (EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:138), API just doesn't provide access to it.